# Vegetable Broth/Stock from Kirkland Organic No-Salt Seasoning

Tags: stock, broth

Is it viable to make stock from store bought Kirkland Organic No-Salt Seasoning?  I'd be ok using a bullion cube but they all seem to be loaded with salt.

Mix with water and bring to a boil.

Ingredients:

Organic  Onion,  Organic  Garlic,  Organic  carrot,  Organic  black  pepper,  organic  red  bell pepper,  Organic  tomato  granules,  Organic  Orange  Peel,  Organic  Parsley, Organic bay leaves, organic thyme, Organic basil, Organic celery, Organic Lemon  peel,  Organic  oregano,  Organic  savory,  Organic  mustard  seed, Organic  cumin,  organic  marjoram,  organic  coriander,  organic  cayenne pepper, citric acid and organic rosemary

Comment: How much salt could a boulion cube have? Certainly no more than the volume of the cube itself. Generally when you make a broth, it needs salt or it tastes insipid, flat and flabby. Just reduce the salt in your recipe by however much boulion cube you are using and it will balance out fine.

Comment: That seems like a pretty legit point regarding the volume of the bullion cube... Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to taste before serving.

Comment: Though I should have mentioned that the people I cook for require very low salt in their diets which is why I prefer to add salt directly.

Comment: Then adjust appropriately, or make your own broth without salt. Just boil down some chicken. It'll taste horrid until it's seasoned, but then at least you have an unsalted broth to start with. You don't have to buy expensive chicken. Cheap parts will work just fine.

Comment: And for the record, I like MUCH less salt that some people, but most food needs _some_ salt or similar seasoning or it's just plain flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment to answer.

How much salt could a boulion cube have? Certainly no more than the volume of the cube itself. Generally when you make a broth, it needs salt or it tastes insipid, flat and flabby. Just reduce the salt in your recipe by however much boulion cube you are using and it will balance out fine.